# How to determine the max file upload limit in php

Tags: php

How can the file upload size allowed by php settings be determined withing a php script?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The upload is limited by three options: **upload_max_filesize**, **post_max_size** and **memory_limit**. Your upload is only done if it doesn't exeed one of them.

The **ini_get()** function provides you with a short hand of the limit and should be converted first. Thx to [AoEmaster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1732818/aoemaster) for this.

```
function return_bytes($val) {
    $val = trim($val);
    $last = strtolower($val[strlen($val)-1]);
    switch($last) 
    {
        case 'g':
        $val *= 1024;
        case 'm':
        $val *= 1024;
        case 'k':
        $val *= 1024;
    }
    return $val;
}

function max_file_upload_in_bytes() {
    //select maximum upload size
    $max_upload = return_bytes(ini_get('upload_max_filesize'));
    //select post limit
    $max_post = return_bytes(ini_get('post_max_size'));
    //select memory limit
    $memory_limit = return_bytes(ini_get('memory_limit'));
    // return the smallest of them, this defines the real limit
    return min($max_upload, $max_post, $memory_limit);
}
```

Source: http://www.kavoir.com/2010/02/php-get-the-file-uploading-limit-max-file-size-allowed-to-upload.html

Comment: Should be noted that this does not account for shorthand notation in ini files, so if you have a limit of "64M" it will be parsed as 64. Best to convert all to bytes before comparing.

Comment: I agree with Brady, most ini files I see now use shorthand notation.

Comment: See this conversion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13076480/php-get-actual-maximum-upload-size

Comment: Made the answer fit the needs.

Comment: Another thing which may limit a file upload is runtime. Check max_execution_time and max_input_time.

Comment: Another thing which may prevent a large file transfer from completing successfully is the temporary directory filling up. PHP sends your file to a temporary loacation such as /tmp/phpE4oNJI, and then moves it to the destination. Check php.ini for upload-tmp-dir. I think the default is /tmp. If this directory is too small to hold your file, you can make it bigger, or change upload-tmp-dir to use a different directory.

Comment: Note: If any of the three ini setttings is set to "unlimited", this code will return 0 or -1. But you cannot say that 0 or -1 indicate no upload limit, as the two other settings might be >0.

Comment: People voting for buggy function. Nice! return_bytes() contains an error. You have to get a numeric part of $val before switch(), e.g $val = substr($val, 0, -1);

Answer (score 14):

Use [`ini_get`](http://php.net/ini_get) to get the current configuration value:

```
ini_get('upload_max_filesize')
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a single function, implementing the original idea from AoEmaster.
The function returns integer (amount of bytes).

```
function _GetMaxAllowedUploadSize(){
    $Sizes = array();
    $Sizes[] = ini_get('upload_max_filesize');
    $Sizes[] = ini_get('post_max_size');
    $Sizes[] = ini_get('memory_limit');
    for($x=0;$x<count($Sizes);$x++){
        $Last = strtolower($Sizes[$x][strlen($Sizes[$x])-1]);
        if($Last == 'k'){
            $Sizes[$x] *= 1024;
        } elseif($Last == 'm'){
            $Sizes[$x] *= 1024;
            $Sizes[$x] *= 1024;
        } elseif($Last == 'g'){
            $Sizes[$x] *= 1024;
            $Sizes[$x] *= 1024;
            $Sizes[$x] *= 1024;
        } elseif($Last == 't'){
            $Sizes[$x] *= 1024;
            $Sizes[$x] *= 1024;
            $Sizes[$x] *= 1024;
            $Sizes[$x] *= 1024;
        }
    }
    return min($Sizes);
}
```

If you want, you can combine it with the following function that renders the output as a human readable text.

```
function _Byte2Size($bytes,$RoundLength=1) {
    $kb = 1024;         // Kilobyte
    $mb = 1024 * $kb;   // Megabyte
    $gb = 1024 * $mb;   // Gigabyte
    $tb = 1024 * $gb;   // Terabyte

    if($bytes < $kb) {
        if(!$bytes){
            $bytes = '0';
        }
        return (($bytes + 1)-1).' B';
    } else if($bytes < $mb) {
        return round($bytes/$kb,$RoundLength).' KB';
    } else if($bytes < $gb) {
        return round($bytes/$mb,$RoundLength).' MB';
    } else if($bytes < $tb) {
        return round($bytes/$gb,$RoundLength).' GB';
    } else {
        return round($bytes/$tb,$RoundLength).' TB';
    }
}
```

Use it this way:

```
echo 'Max allowed upload size: '._Byte2Size(_GetMaxAllowedUploadSize());
```

A result could be:

*Max allowed upload size: 500 MB*

Answer (score 1):

You can also change that size at runtime using the .htaccess file without the need to change your php.ini file

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 1224M
php_value post_max_size 1224M
php_value max_execution_time 3000
php_value max_input_time 3000
```

copy that code and put your file, then store that file with index file then you run your project you also capable to upload 1GB file

for more detail [read this article](http://www.wordcomat.com/how-to-increase-the-file-uploading-size-using-htaccess-file/)

Answer (score 1):

```
function return_bytes($val) 
{
    $val = trim($val);
    $last = strtolower($val[strlen($val)-1]);

    switch($last) 
    {
        case 'g':
        $val *= 1024;
        case 'm':
        $val *= 1024;
        case 'k':
        $val *= 1024;
    }

    return $val;
}

function get_upload_max_filesize()
{
    $max_upload = return_bytes(ini_get('upload_max_filesize'));
    $max_post = return_bytes(ini_get('post_max_size'));
    return min($max_upload, $max_post);
}
```

Answer (score -3):

You can set Maximum file upload size using ini_set()

```
  ini_set('post_max_size', '64M');
  ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '64M');
```

or 
using the .htaccess file

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 
php_value post_max_size
```

Comment: Some of these settings can be changed inside a .php script using ini_set, and some can't. See http://php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php for the full list. For example post_max_size says:

"PHP_INI_PERDIR  PHP_INI_SYSTEM in PHP <= 4.2.3. Available since PHP 4.0.3."

In order to decipher what "PHP_INI_PERDIR" means, see http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.modes.php

PHP_INI_PERDIR  Entry can be set in php.ini, .htaccess, httpd.conf or .user.ini (since PHP 5.3) 

So post_max_size cannot be set in a PHP script via ini_set().