# PHP get actual maximum upload size

Tags: php

When using

```
ini_get("upload_max_filesize");
```

it actually gives you the string specified in the php.ini file.

It is not good to use this value as a reference for the maximum upload size because

- it is possible to use so-called [shorthandbytes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.using.php#faq.using.shorthandbytes) like `1M` and so on which needs alot of additional parsing
- when upload_max_filesize is for example `0.25M`, it actually is ZERO, making the parsing of the value much harder once again
- also, if the value contains any spaces like it is interpreted as ZERO by php, while it shows the value without spaces when using `ini_get`

So, is there any way to get the value actually being used by PHP, besides the one reported by `ini_get`, or what is the best way to determinate it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to determine the max file upload limit in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2840755/how-to-determine-the-max-file-upload-limit-in-php)

Comment: `(int)ini_get("upload_max_filesize")*1024` will convert it to kbs. E.g. 2M -> 2048

Comment: @AfrazAhmad i think you miss the point, the upload_max_filesize setting may not be in megabyte

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Drupal has this implemented fairly elegantly:

```
// Returns a file size limit in bytes based on the PHP upload_max_filesize
// and post_max_size
function file_upload_max_size() {
  static $max_size = -1;

  if ($max_size < 0) {
    // Start with post_max_size.
    $post_max_size = parse_size(ini_get('post_max_size'));
    if ($post_max_size > 0) {
      $max_size = $post_max_size;
    }

    // If upload_max_size is less, then reduce. Except if upload_max_size is
    // zero, which indicates no limit.
    $upload_max = parse_size(ini_get('upload_max_filesize'));
    if ($upload_max > 0 && $upload_max < $max_size) {
      $max_size = $upload_max;
    }
  }
  return $max_size;
}

function parse_size($size) {
  $unit = preg_replace('/[^bkmgtpezy]/i', '', $size); // Remove the non-unit characters from the size.
  $size = preg_replace('/[^0-9\.]/', '', $size); // Remove the non-numeric characters from the size.
  if ($unit) {
    // Find the position of the unit in the ordered string which is the power of magnitude to multiply a kilobyte by.
    return round($size * pow(1024, stripos('bkmgtpezy', $unit[0])));
  }
  else {
    return round($size);
  }
}
```

The above functions are available anywhere in Drupal, or you can copy it and use it in your own project subject to the terms of the GPL license version 2 or later.

As for parts 2 and 3 of your question, you will need to parse the `php.ini` file directly. These are essentially configuration errors, and PHP is resorting to fallback behaviors. It appears you can actually get the location of the loaded `php.ini` file in PHP, although trying to read from it may not work with basedir or safe-mode enabled:

```
$max_size = -1;
$post_overhead = 1024; // POST data contains more than just the file upload; see comment from @jlh
$files = array_merge(array(php_ini_loaded_file()), explode(",\n", php_ini_scanned_files()));
foreach (array_filter($files) as $file) {
  $ini = parse_ini_file($file);
  $regex = '/^([0-9]+)([bkmgtpezy])$/i';
  if (!empty($ini['post_max_size']) && preg_match($regex, $ini['post_max_size'], $match)) {
    $post_max_size = round($match[1] * pow(1024, stripos('bkmgtpezy', strtolower($match[2])));
    if ($post_max_size > 0) {
      $max_size = $post_max_size - $post_overhead;
    }
  }
  if (!empty($ini['upload_max_filesize']) && preg_match($regex, $ini['upload_max_filesize'], $match)) {
    $upload_max_filesize = round($match[1] * pow(1024, stripos('bkmgtpezy', strtolower($match[2])));
    if ($upload_max_filesize > 0 && ($max_size <= 0 || $max_size > $upload_max_filesize) {
      $max_size = $upload_max_filesize;
    }
  }
}

echo $max_size;
```

Comment: The `pow` line is quite elegant, but yet this only solves one of the 3 listed problems in the question.

Comment: Well, the other two problems are really configuration errors more than valid situations that need to be accounted for. But for the sake of checking for configuration errors, that could only be done by reading the php.ini file directly, before PHP tries to parse the invalid entries. And since php.ini could be anywhere, this is not a stable or cross-platform way to check active configuration. What about `$ini = parse_ini_file('/etc/php.ini'); $ini['upload_max_filesize']`?

Comment: Just to clarify, since my previous comment I have updated the post with some code to find the active `php.ini` file and parse it directly.

Comment: This seems to be the best option to me for now. If the php.ini is not readable, just fall back to ini_get(). Very nice.

Comment: If this limit is actually enforced, which I assume it is, is it handled by the Apache or CGI-controllers that allow php to run? How do *they* handle it? [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) says we should find the internal mechanism for converting this into bytes rather than bloating our own code (assuming we're not running Drupal already).

Comment: @SeldomNeedy: I would assume this is handled in mod_php. The user is always free to send whatever crap down the line, and this would just be the limit before PHP gives up on the stream and just dumps the rest of it. As for DRY...well this is PHP, so I'd guess that maybe you could get the internal implementation with Zend but otherwise you're about as out of luck as you are with all the other inaccessible internal state.

Comment: Note: `post_max_size=0` also indicates no limit since PHP 5.3.2 / 5.2.12, but imho the above code would return `0`. (It should return the value of `upload_max_filesize` instead if this is not also `0`).

Comment: Fixed in the first code. If both are `0`, this code should return `-1`. The configured value for `post_max_size` or `upload_max_filesize ` needs to pass `$post_max_size > 0` or `$upload_max_filesize > 0`, respectively.

Comment: Important: If the max size is restricted by the post size, then only files slightly smaller than the configured size can be uploaded, since the post data also contains other information, for example the file name and content type.  Subtracting 1024 bytes of overhead seems to work well.

Comment: Good catch, @jlh! I've modified the final example code to subtract a constant `$post_overhead = 1024` from the `post_max_size` when that is the limiting factor.

Answer (score 47):

Here is the full solution. It takes care of all traps like the shorthand byte notation and also considers post_max_size:

```
/**
* This function returns the maximum files size that can be uploaded 
* in PHP
* @returns int File size in bytes
**/
function getMaximumFileUploadSize()  
{  
    return min(convertPHPSizeToBytes(ini_get('post_max_size')), convertPHPSizeToBytes(ini_get('upload_max_filesize')));  
}  

/**
* This function transforms the php.ini notation for numbers (like '2M') to an integer (2*1024*1024 in this case)
* 
* @param string $sSize
* @return integer The value in bytes
*/
function convertPHPSizeToBytes($sSize)
{
    //
    $sSuffix = strtoupper(substr($sSize, -1));
    if (!in_array($sSuffix,array('P','T','G','M','K'))){
        return (int)$sSize;  
    } 
    $iValue = substr($sSize, 0, -1);
    switch ($sSuffix) {
        case 'P':
            $iValue *= 1024;
            // Fallthrough intended
        case 'T':
            $iValue *= 1024;
            // Fallthrough intended
        case 'G':
            $iValue *= 1024;
            // Fallthrough intended
        case 'M':
            $iValue *= 1024;
            // Fallthrough intended
        case 'K':
            $iValue *= 1024;
            break;
    }
    return (int)$iValue;
}
```

Comment: I had no idea how this actually worked (specifically, the switch statement) until I eventually realised that there is only one single "break" statement in the switch statement, and the order of the "case" lines is important.  It works great, but I dread the thought of some junior programmer going back and attempting to modify this code later.  Perhaps a "more standardised" version would be a better long-term solution?

Comment: Well, this doesn't really solve the problems I mentioned in the question, as it just uses ini_get() ;-) We have already had many answers like this one.

Comment: @GavinG I have added now proper comments as required by PSR-2 so the fallthrough is obvious.

Comment: link is dead...

Comment: What about zero and -1 ... if value is set to these , it means there is no limit

Answer (score 11):

This is what I use:

```
function asBytes($ini_v) {
   $ini_v = trim($ini_v);
   $s = [ 'g'=> 1<<30, 'm' => 1<<20, 'k' => 1<<10 ];
   return intval($ini_v) * ($s[strtolower(substr($ini_v,-1))] ?: 1);
}
```

Comment: in 2020 we can use kbs <?php
function kbs($v){
   return intval($v) * ([ 'p'=> 1<<40, 't' => 1<<30, 'g'=> 1<<20, 'm' => 1<<10, 'k' => 1 ][strtolower(substr(trim($v),-1))] ?: 1);
}
echo(kbs('1g'));
?>

Comment: Love this ! I just love short simple code !!!

Answer (score 5):

Looks like it isn't possible.

Because of this, I am going to continue using this code:

```
function convertBytes( $value ) {
    if ( is_numeric( $value ) ) {
        return $value;
    } else {
        $value_length = strlen($value);
        $qty = substr( $value, 0, $value_length - 1 );
        $unit = strtolower( substr( $value, $value_length - 1 ) );
        switch ( $unit ) {
            case 'k':
                $qty *= 1024;
                break;
            case 'm':
                $qty *= 1048576;
                break;
            case 'g':
                $qty *= 1073741824;
                break;
        }
        return $qty;
    }
}
$maxFileSize = convertBytes(ini_get('upload_max_filesize'));
```

Originally from [this](http://www.php.net/manual/de/faq.using.php#78405) helpful php.net comment.

**STILL OPEN TO ACCEPT BETTER ANSWERS**

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so, at least not in the way you have defined it. There are so many other factors that come into consideration for maximum file upload size, most notably the connection speed of the user as well as the timeout setting for the web server as well as the PHP process(es).

A more useful metric for you might be to decide what is a reasonable maximum file size for the types of files you expect to receive for a given input. Make the decision on what is reasonable for your use case and set a policy around that.

Comment: Sure, that is what I'm doing. But I still absolutely need to know if the allowed size in php.ini is lower the my recommended max size.

Answer (score -1):

Well you can always use this syntax, which will give you correct numbers from PHP ini file:

```
$maxUpload      = (int)(ini_get('upload_max_filesize'));
$maxPost        = (int)(ini_get('post_max_size'));
```

Mart

Comment: Did you even read the opening post? `echo ini_get('post_max_size'); -> 8M` 
`echo (int)(ini_get('post_max_size'));-> 8`