# By what mechanism (if any) is php.ini's upload_max_filesize enforced?

Tags: php, apache, fastcgi, php-ini

After looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13076480/) about `upload_max_filesize`, I started to wonder: since `ini_get` simply returns the raw string-value (e.g. '15M'), what component actually reads this value and then uses it to limit uploads? Would it be Apache or the CGI-engine? Or is this handled by essential PHP-runtimes instead?

For the former, I would assume that most softwares which can serve PHP-pages have a way of converting this [shorthand](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.using.php#faq.using.shorthandbytes) ini-value to bytes (or some machine-usable integer) and then notifying PHP when this limit has been exceeded during a POST action. Is this indeed the case? (Maybe PHP converts the string first?)

**TL;DR:** What component is responsible for picking up the `upload_max_size` value and passing it to the enforcement mechanism(s)? Or alternatively: Does this setting indeed exist strictly to allow a DIY-implementation of this limit?

**Why I ask:** The answers given in the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13076480/) are <strike>somewhat</strike> unsatisfactory because they all basically suggest various blocks of "here paste this code" to convert the string. What's missing is any information about the location of internal mechanisms that already do this for PHP, so that it/they can be used directly, or at least faithfully emulated.

Comment: Seems highly likely to me, that it depends on how you are running PHP.

Comment: It does not depend on how you run php: if request comes through `HTTP POST` the corresponding handler is invoked that performs a check. Grep for `SAPI_POST_HANDLER_FUNC` through php sources.

Comment: @zerkms Looks like the actual limiting itself boils down to about what you would expect inside main/rfc1867.c, which is `if (PG(upload_max_filesize) > 0 && (zend_long)(total_bytes+blen) > PG(upload_max_filesize)) { /* complain */ }`. I think this has something to do PHP's globally-accessible INI-values, but I can't figure out at the moment is where anything like `zend_long PG(zend_long someInput)` is defined...

Comment: I'm not sure understand what your current problem/question is.