# Limit the allowed file size for <input type=file> in pure HTML (no JS)

Tags: html, w3c

There are several topics* about setting up a max file size for a `input type=file`, but there is apparently no pure-standard HTML way to do so (nothing in the HTML spec).

So, is there any *pure-HTML* way to set a max file size on a `input type="file"`?

Is there a request for such feature, like a `maxsize="..."` attribute to let the browser filter out the files the user can selected, or do we have to stick to Javascript File API for years (or ever)?

---

*Topics:

JS File API: [Limit the size of an file upload (html input)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5697605/limit-the-size-of-an-file-upload-html-input) or [How to check file input size with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601455/how-to-check-file-input-size-with-jquery#3937404)

HTML never-saw-that-in-any-standard: [HTML Upload MAX_FILE_SIZE does not appear to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6327965/html-upload-max-file-size-does-not-appear-to-work)

Comment: HTML isn't server side language, so no processing can happen when files are uploaded. You would only need this in a language to deal with the files being uploaded, like PHP.

Comment: @Lee: It is not about any kind of “processing”, but simply about notifying the user upfront if the file they chose is larger than what the server is willing to handle.

Comment: HTML will never know that, YOur best option would probably be to use PHP to get the file upload limit, and echo that. Googling found this for me - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13076480/php-get-actual-maximum-upload-size

Comment: That's a false argument. HTML doesn't "know" the extension or MIME type of the file that's being chosen either, yet file inputs have an accept attribute that allow you to filter them which the corresponding system file dialog will gladly honor.

Answer (score 6):

This is not part of the HTML spec, so there is no "pure HTML" way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I could only find this [mention from 2013](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-whatwg-archive/2013Oct/0034.html) with no reaction. Couldn't find any mentions in https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues

Sounds like it's something you could suggest, see [FAQ - Is there a process for adding new features to a specification?](https://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/FAQ#Is_there_a_process_for_adding_new_features_to_a_specification.3F) for the recommended way to suggest new features to the working group. Please post the link to the discussion here if you do bring it up.

Though since there's a JS workaround, I guess this won't be high on anyone's to-do list.