# PHP script for files upload - can't upload files bigger than ~1MB

Tags: php, .htaccess, file-upload, upload

I'm using a PHP script to upload doc/docx/pdf to my server. As long as the file size isn't bigger than 1MB, I don't have any issues with the upload, however the moment it's around 1MB, it just won't upload at all.

I updated the values in my .htaccess to the following:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 10M
php_value post_max_size 10M
php_value max_input_time 300
php_value max_execution_time 300
php_value memory_limit 96M
```

There are no errors or warnings in the log file. I'm using the below code to upload the files:

```
    $checkUpload = $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"];
    $target_dir = realpath(dirname(__FILE__)) . "/uploads/";
    $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
    $newfilename = 'newfilename' . end($temp);
    $target_file = $target_dir . $newfilename;
    $uploadOk = 1;
    $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    if (($imageFileType != "pdf") && ($imageFileType != "doc") && ($imageFileType != "docx")) {
        echo "wrong format!";
        die();
    }
    if ($uploadOk == 0) {
        echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
    } else {
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_dir . $newfilename)) {
        } else {
            echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
        }
    }
```

I have restarted the apache after updates and checked the max size with the below script:

```
$max_upload = (int)(ini_get('upload_max_filesize'));
$max_post = (int)(ini_get('post_max_size'));
$memory_limit = (int)(ini_get('memory_limit'));
$upload_mb = min($max_upload, $max_post, $memory_limit);
echo $upload_mb;
```

The above confirms maximum size is 10M. I'm not even looking into uploading more than 5MB and can't figure out what the issue is.

E: I changed the values in php.ini, but it still doesn't work. I'm using PHP 7.0 with apache 2.4 on debian 8.

E2: I tried to upload the files using a WordPress plugin (Caldera Forms) and after a few battles this seems to be getting through to regular uploads folder (even with 4MB files). The issue is, I don't think using a plugin is a solution and I'd like to understand why I can't do it my way.

I'm currently getting the following warning:

*PHP Warning:  move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpThmBZJ' to '/var/www/mywebsite.com/uploads/form_uploads/1234.doc' in /var/www/mywebsite.com/public_html/wp-content/themes/mytheme/add_file.php on line 85, referer: http://mywebsite.com/*

It would suggest a permission issue, but:

- the caldera form files are still getting through
- I made sure
  the apache is currently the owner of www and the relevant uploads
  folder
- upload folder permissions are set to 755

Update: since I started receiving the above warning, I can't even upload the small files anymore.

Thanks for help,
E.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ini\_set("upload\_max\_filesize","200M") not working in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13442270/ini-setupload-max-filesize-200m-not-working-in-php)

Comment: Please see these existing questions about the max upload size in PHP:
 [PHP get actual maximum upload size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13076480/php-get-actual-maximum-upload-size),  [ini_set upload_max_filesize not working in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13442270/ini-setupload-max-filesize-200m-not-working-in-php),  [overriding upload_max_filesize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949415/overriding-upload-max-filesize)

Comment: All these values can be set in .htaccess. Also, when checked with any script, not only the one I provided above, but also the ones in the answers you suggested, it still returns 10MB as the set maximum upload value, but this doesn't affect the upload itself in any way.

Comment: Have you checked with your hosting provider if they have server-level restrictions?

Comment: I have now updated the settings in the relevant php.ini too (restarted apache afterwards), but nothing changed. It's on one of the VM instances in Google Cloud Platform, so there shouldn't be any restrictions either. @FluffyKitten