# How to check files for upload_max_filesize and post_max_size prior to upload?

Tags: php, file-upload, upload-max-filesize

How can I check uploading files for upload_max_filesize, post_max_size and max_file_uploads **on the server side**? If files are bigger than these values, they don't even get to the file array. So I obviously can't get the files sizes and compare them to values. How can I prevent file uploads which are bigger than these?

Some say the error may be obtained from `$_FILES['file']['error']`. So if I get the files as

```
$this->request->files->get('my_file')
foreach ($files as $file) {
...
```

how do I get that error?

[UPDATE} Working solution for upload_max_filesize:

```
$file->getErrorMessage();
```

The error I get :

```
"The file "2.6MB.avi" exceeds your upload_max_filesize ini directive (limit is 2048 KiB)."
```

Comment: Check [this](https://gist.github.com/svizion/2343619), you can use `ini_get("upload_max_filesize");` aswell, more answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13076480/php-get-actual-maximum-upload-size/25370978)

Comment: You seem to miss my point - I know how to get the php max values, the problem is if the uploading file is greater then that, the files array is NULL so I don't even get to know its size and compare it to the limit. e.g. the upload_max_filesize = 2MB and the file is 10MB. How do you get the file's size if the files array is NULL, it simply doesn't upload by the script

Comment: `PHP` is checking the `file size` once its uploaded, if you an empty or null `array` , then check how you pass data for any possible `errors`!

Comment: ok, I got it (updated above)

Comment: You still need to add the `getErrorMessage()` function to your code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get file size before uploading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7497404/get-file-size-before-uploading)

Comment: well, that's half of the problem, that only catches the upload_max_filesize. How do I catch the post_max_size and max_file_uploads?