# Laravel 5.3, check if uploaded file is bigger than upload_max_filesize (optional upload)

Tags: php, laravel, upload

In Laravel 5.3, I'm trying to catch if an uploaded file has a bigger file size than upload_max_filesize. The upload field is not required.

I tried this method, but it doesn't work

```
public function checkFile($field)
{
    if (request()->hasFile($field)){ // check if field is present
        $file = request()->file($field);
        if (!$file->isValid()){ // now check if it's valid
            return back()->with('error', $file->getErrorMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

I can't use just `if (!$file->isValid())` because file field is optional and i get a `Call to a member function isValid() on null` if field is empty.

So I have to check if field is present using `if (request()->hasFile($field))`, but this doesn't work for big files, since `dd(request()->hasFile('picture'))` returns `false`.

Of course I can rely on default Laravel Validator messages, but I get a dummy `The picture failed to upload.` that doesn't give any clue to the user.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2840755/how-to-determine-the-max-file-upload-limit-in-php

Comment: Check out my answer

Answer (score 6):

Laravel Validation will work only if the filesize you are uploading is less than the limit set in php.ini.

If you try to upload a file larger than the limit, PHP will not forward the request to Laravel, and will error straight away. Hence, Laravel cannot do anything in this scenario.

One way to fix this is to set a much larger limit in php.ini and then validating the file size in Laravel.

Answer (score 4):

You should consider using the built in Laravel form request validation system. There is a built in validation rule which lets you specify a `max` file size, you can check out the docs here:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#rule-max

Your rule would look something like this:

```
[
    'video' => 'max:256'
]
```

This would fail if the file uploaded was a greater size than 256kb.

You mentioned that you didn't like Laravel's built in validation error messages. No problem! You can change them in the `resources/lang/en/validation.php` language file, this is the line you'd need to change:

https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/resources/lang/en/validation.php#L51

Comment: uhm... this kind of validation works for file above the 'max' threshold but BELOW the upload_max_filesize setting, and doesn't work for file ABOVE the upload_max_filesize setting...

Comment: No form of server side validation will work if your `upload_max_filesize` setting is too low - you need to increase this.

Comment: As the OP commented, this solution doesn't help since the "max" rule is never checked if the file failed to upload.

Comment: @Ivan uhm.... Laravel doesn't even get the request if you try and upload a file above the upload_max_filesize setting. PHP itself will fail outright, and the request won't even make it to the web application. If you want Laravel - or any PHP application, for that matter - to handle filesize validation, you *have* to increase this limit.

Comment: This should work. But you should have the same limit in your PHP config and your Laravel config.

Comment: That's the point of the question if I understood correctly: to send a proper error message when the uploaded file is bigger than the max size allowed in `php ini`. I showed in my answer that it is in fact possible to handle this particular error in Laravel. Unfortunately it has been downvoted without a comment, so I don't know why people think that may not work. cc @Ivan

Comment: You're not understanding, @Alejandro: If the filesize is larger than what is designated in php.ini, PHP rejects the request entirely and *Laravel never receives the request at all*. If Laravel never receives the request, how can it create an error message?

Comment: @maiorano84 ok, thanks for replying. Based on your comment I realize now that there are 2 `ini` limits: `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size`. My answer handled the case where the uploaded file exceeded the file size, but the overall request size was within the limit. I'm updating my anwer with the second case

Comment: @maiorano84 ended up adding a second answer, since they both cover different things. I'd like to know what you think of it

Answer (score 2):

[My previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40805980/3208258) handled the case where an uploaded file was bigger than the `upload_max_filesize` setting in `php.ini`. But failed when the size of the file made the Request be larger than the `post_max_size` (another `php.ini` setting). This case is harder to handle because the inputs (the `$_POST` global, if we handled plain PHP) get cleared.

I think a Middleware is a good place to do this "validation":

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{
    $post_max_size = ini_get('post_max_size') * 1024 * 1024;
    $content_length = $request->server('HTTP_CONTENT_LENGTH') ?: $request->server('CONTENT_LENGTH') ?: 0;

    $response = $next($request);

    if ($content_length > $post_max_size)
    {
        return redirect()->back()->with('errors', collect([trans('validation.max.file', ['max' => 2000])]));
    }

    return $response;
}
```

(As I said, this won't preserve the input.)

Answer (score 1):

## Server side code(In Controller):

Below function is taken from drupal by meustrus author at his [stack answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13076480/php-get-actual-maximum-upload-size) and I taken here as example.
*Start with post_max_size*

```
// Returns a file size limit in bytes based on the PHP upload_max_filesize
// and post_max_size
$max_size = parse_size(ini_get('post_max_size'));

// If upload_max_size is less, then reduce. Except if upload_max_size is
// zero, which indicates no limit.
$upload_max = parse_size(ini_get('upload_max_filesize'));
if ($upload_max > 0 && $upload_max < $max_size) {
  $max_size = $upload_max;
}

//Get max upload file size limit...
$file_upload_max_size = $max_size;
```

*Public function to parse size*

```
public function parse_size($size) {
  $unit = preg_replace('/[^bkmgtpezy]/i', '', $size); // Remove the non-unit characters from the size.
  $size = preg_replace('/[^0-9\.]/', '', $size); // Remove the non-numeric characters from the size.
  if ($unit) {
    // Find the position of the unit in the ordered string which is the power of magnitude to multiply a kilobyte by.
    return round($size * pow(1024, stripos('bkmgtpezy', $unit[0])));
  }
  else {
    return round($size);
  }
}
```

*Set compact for send 'file_upload_max_size' value to blade*

```
return view('YOURBLADEPATH',compact('file_upload_max_size'));
```

## JS Validation(In Blade):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.forms[0].addEventListener('submit', function( evt ) {
    var file = document.getElementById('file').files[0];

    if(file && file.size < '{$file_upload_max_size}') { // 10 MB (this size is in bytes)
        //Submit form        
    } else {
        //Prevent default and display error
        evt.preventDefault();
    }
}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, I use JavaScript to validate file sizes.

*JavaScript

```
function validate_size(elm) {
    var file = elm.files[0];
    var max_size = {{ env('UPLOAD_MAX_FILESIZE', 2097152) }}; // in bytes, e.g. 2 MB = 2097152 Bytes
    var size_name = {{ floor(env('UPLOAD_MAX_FILESIZE', 2097152) / 1024 / 1024) }}; // result: 2

    if (file && file.size < max_size) {
        // CONTINUE
    } else {
        // PREVENT AND DISPLAY ERROR
        alert('File size cannot be greater than ' + size_name + ' MB');
        // RESET INPUT FILE VALUE
        elm.value = '';
    }
}
```

*HTML/Laravel Blade

```
...
<input type="file" name="photo" onchange="validate_size(this)">
...
```

Then it will alert the user if they select a file with a size greater than the allowed size.

Answer (score -1):

The default behaviour for Laravel file validator is to reject the file if the upload was not ok, for whatever reason. Validation rules then are not applied, so a "max" rule can't help you here.
You clearly want in this case a custom message for this type of error (max file size exceeded). I think extending the Validator class is an elegant solution.

```
use Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile;
use Illuminate\Validation\Validator;

class UploadSizeValidator extends Validator
{
    protected function validateAttribute($attribute, $rule)
    {
        $value = $this->getValue($attribute);

        if ($value instanceof UploadedFile && $value->getError() != UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
            switch ($value->getError()) {
                case UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE:
                    return $this->addFailure($attribute, 'max_file_size_exceeded', []);
                // check additional UPLOAD_ERR_XXX constants if you want to handle other errors
            }
        }

        return parent::validateAttribute($attribute, $rule);
    }
}
```

Now, how do you tell the framework to use your validator instead of the default one? You can set a resolver function on the Validator Factory:

```
// do this in a 'boot' method of a ServiceProvider
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

Validator::resolver(function($translator, $data, $rules, $messages, $customAttributes) {
    return new UploadSizeValidator($translator, $data, $rules, $messages, $customAttributes);
});
```

Finally set an appropriate message for the key 'max_file_size_exceeded' in the `validation.php` lang file.

Comment: Uhm... seems a little bit complex: I noticed that there is a `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile` class that has all the methods I'd need, isn't there a simple way to use it BEFORE any other validation occurs, and redirect the user to previous page if file is too big?

Comment: @Ivan yes, it's possible. How are you validating? In the controller with `$this->validate` or do you have a FormRequest class with the validation rules?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I was not at home in the last 10 days :-( Yes, I use `$this->validate`: I just saw your answer: it's ok to get redirected without preserving input, but I'd like to avoid a middleware